# Switching between the same two tabs only in a browser using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

My idea of what am trying to do is 
When I open a website on one tab of an internet explorer broweser and click on a link it should open a new tab in the same browser with a pdf page init ... the pdf page has a lot of links which if u try clicking on any of them they should take you back to the old tab where u managed to lunch open the pdf from and keep switching between those two tabs only 
I hope the idea is clear .. am trying to do this using html and javascript ... this what I wrote but am still missing a lot here. Thanks in advance for any help provided

this piece here lunches another instant in another window

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function son()
{

 myWindow=window.open('','','width=500,height=500');
 myWindow.document.write(" SON !");
 myWindow.focus();
 myWindow.opener.document.write("<p> DAD !</p>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Open " onclick="son()" />

</body>
</html>
```

This file is where I have the pdf file built in.

```
<object data="Test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

<p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
you can <a href="Test.pdf">click here to
download the PDF file.</a></p>

</object>
```

thanks again

Comment: You can't force a switch to a different tab or window via JavaScript.

Comment: If the opened page were a Web page, you could possibly do something like this with `postMessage` (but even that wouldn't switch tabs), but I suspect it will not be possible with a PDF.

Comment: @zzzzBov  even if I try putting the pdf in a iframe

Answer (score 7):

In the old days, you could use a window's `focus` method to bring a window/tab into the foreground.  However, abuse (mostly in the form of advertisers' popup windows) has resulted in browsers restricting or disabling that functionality.

If we ignore the PDF part, conceptually, this is a very simple request.  First, open a window and hold on to its reference:

```
var pop = window.open('page.html'); // opens in new tab on most browsers
```

In the secondary page, switching back to the original was simple:

```
window.opener.focus(); // no longer works in most modern browsers
```

And from the first page, to switch back:

```
pop.focus();  // might work
```

In [my test](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/DvSsE/), I couldn't get IE 9 or Chrome 21 to switch back to the opener tab.  In Chrome, I could open the second page, manually switch back to the original tab, and calling `pop.focus()` did bring the second tab back in focus.  (IE did nothing.)  I was able to force Chrome back to the opening page by calling `window.opener.alert('...');` from the secondary page, but that's an ugly hack.

So it looks like you won't be able to pull this off, at least not reliably.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish (a TOC?), but have you thought about opening two windows?  Open one with your links that covers the left-hand side of the screen, and another on the other half with the PDF.

Comment: can u give me a simple example of a TOC, so I can absorb what are u trying to explain to me, it would be a great help thanks in advance

Comment: Josh u mentioned a point about the "opener", so it doesnot work at all, or its just the opener.focus ? thanks again

Comment: TOC = Table of Contents.  `window.opener` works (it points to the `window` object of the window that opened the current window), but its `focus` method fails silently.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not have APIs for controlling tabs.  Therefore, you can't do it.

You can open windows, but you can't control if it will be a tab or window.

Comment: How would putting something in frame change the fact that JavaScript can't control tabs?  Can you name one native JavaScript function for switching tabs?

Are you referring to browser tabs or tabs you make within a page?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative possibility involves NOT opening a second window or tab.
If you open another/replacing page in the current window or tab,
you can use the History object to switch between the two pages.

```
history.go(-1); //takes you back to previous page
history.go(1);  //takes you forward to the page from which you went back.
```