# How to switch browser tabs when using target='name'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a site which has a glossary (`/glossary#item-name`). So far I have been linking to it like this: `<a href="/glossary#item-name" target="glossary">item</a>`, but I realised that although it opens and switches to the 'glossary' tab when you click the first link, it then does not switch to the glossary tab when you click other links - it simply reloads it (and jumps to whatever anchor is set).

What can I do to force the browser to switch tabs? I don't want to use `target="_blank"` because every time you click on a link it opens a new tab, which is a pain for the user, but is this all I can do? I am on Chrome 30.0 and am building the site using Bootstrap R3, jQuery and PHP if it helps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible, but take a look to this other posts:

[Javascript - How to make a browser switch tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123950/javascript-how-to-make-a-browser-switch-tabs)
[Switching between the same two tabs only in a browser using javascript and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144135/switching-between-the-same-two-tabs-only-in-a-browser-using-javascript-and-html)